# too much recursion jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an issue of too much recursion with jquery and in IE a pop up stack overflow, what it can be?

Here my code

Html :

```
<div id="leiki_tabs">
<div id="leiki_container">
<ul id="leiki_menu">
  <li style="width:100px;border-right:1px dotted #333;border-bottom:1px dotted #333;text-align:center;"><a id="title_leiki_panel_1" href="#" rel="leiki_panel_1">Today</a></li>
  <li style="width:100px;border-right:1px dotted #333;border-bottom:1px dotted #333;text-align:center;"><a id="title_leiki_panel_2" href="#" rel="leiki_panel_2">This Month</a></li>
  <li style="width:100px;border-right:1px dotted #333;border-bottom:1px dotted #333;text-align:center;"><a id="title_leiki_panel_3" href="#" rel="leiki_panel_3">Archive</a></li>

  <li style="width:270px;"/>
  <li id="leiki_logo_tab_menu"><a href="#" rel="leiki_panel_5" ><img id="leiki_logo" style="border:0px;" src="leikiLogo_onMouseOver.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!--Panel Contents Start-->
<div id="leiki_panel_1" class="leiki_panel">
  <ul class="leiki_panel_ul">
    <li class="leiki_panel_li"><div class="leiki_left"><Article 1</div></li>
    <li class="leiki_panel_li"><div class="leiki_left">Article 2</div></li>
    <li class="leiki_panel_li"><div class="leiki_left">Article 3</div></li>
    <li class="leiki_panel_li"><div class="leiki_left">Article </div></li>
    <li class="leiki_panel_li"><div class="leiki_left">Article 5</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
var opened_one = null;
$(function(){
    $('div[id*="leiki_panel"]').hide();
    $('div[id="leiki_panel_1"]').show();
    $('#title_leiki_panel_1').addClass("leiki_menu_highlight");
    $('#leiki_menu a').mouseenter(function(){
        $('a[id*="title_leiki_panel"]').removeClass("leiki_menu_highlight");
        if(opened_one==null){$('div[id="leiki_panel_1"]').hide();}
        $(opened_one).hide();
        var link_rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('div#' + link_rel).show();
        opened_one = $('div#' + link_rel);
        var tab = "title_" +link_rel;
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var link_rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        var tab = "title_" +link_rel;
        if(tab=="title_leiki_panel_1" ||
        tab=="title_leiki_panel_2" ||
        tab=="title_leiki_panel_3" ||
        tab=="title_leiki_panel_4" ||
        tab=="title_leiki_panel_5"){
        $("#"+tab).addClass("leiki_menu_highlight");}
    });
});
```

It's working on my desktop without problem but on the test server which is owned by our customer it give me this error too much recursion. I cant post the address of the test server but maybe in private message.

Cheers

Comment: Can we see some example HTML that this JS is running on? It'll be getting into a loop somewhere, but it's hard to know where without seeing the HTML as well.

Comment: can you add some debuging in your code ? It looks as if there are loads of elements in your page and are being added to stack to perform some task. Or can you provide a demo page so we can have a look?

Comment: the problem is it's integrated in a page of a newspaper of 5000 lines, and it doenst give me informations :s

Comment: the problem is the test page is on the server of one of our customers, and i cant modify or give you access to it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$('#leiki_menu a').mouseenter(function()` and similar into:

```
$('#leiki_menu').delegate('a', 'mouseenter', function(){
    // ...
}).delegate('a', 'mouseleave', function(){
    // ...
});
```